# How to create dynamic table in pyqt5 and save them as a text file?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, pyqt4, pyqt5

I want to create a widget, which is used for mapping. The widget should contain a push button (Add), which when clicked should add rows and only 2 columns, so that user can enter the value. I want to create a table that allows dynamic creation of rows and user input.

[This is how the ui should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsMCS.png)

After creating this form, I would like to save this form as a txt file but with comma separated values.
The text file would have values like:

Left1,Right1

Left2,Right2

Any sort of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your question. And btw put the image directly into the post

Comment: @MetaColon I have changed the question, but I do not understand why the image is still displayed as a link

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @MetaColon I am unable to hardlink teh images as I have less reputation points :D It is weird but isnt it easy to just open the link in another tab and see , as its just a ui.